# How do I pipe a file line by line into multiple read variables?

Tags: bash

I have a file that contains information in two columns:

```
box1 a1
box2 a2
```

I'm trying to read this file line by line into `read` and have each line items be put into a variable.

On the first pass, `$a` would contain `box1` and `$b` would contain `a1`.

On the second pass, `$a` would contain `box2` and `$b` would contain `a2`, etc.

An example of the code that I am using to try to achieve is this:

```
for i in text.txt; do
    while read line; do
        echo $line | read a b;
    done < text.txt;
    echo $a $b;
done
```

This gives me the following results:

```
box1 a1 box2 a2
```

When I expected the following results:

```
box1 a1
box2 a1
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 78):

Piping into a `read` command causes the variables to be set in a subshell, which makes them inaccessible (indeed, they are gone) to the rest of your code. In this case, though, you don't even need the `for` loop or the second `read` command:

```
while read -r a b; do
    echo "$a" "$b"
done < text.txt
```

Comment: Bingo! That worked like a charm.. Thank you for the explanation, it cleared things up for me. (@chepner and @Dave Jarvis.. Thank you!)

Comment: If you can have `\` in your input, do not forget to use the `-r` argument to read.

Comment: @jfgagne, I researched -r and I found the following in oracle docs - "By default, unless the -r option is specified, backslash (\\) acts as an escape character." is this what you meant?

Comment: @mlebel: yes, you need to use `-r`, because if you have an input line like `box1 foo\nbar` without `-r` you will loose the `\`.

Comment: @jfgagne did the SO comment system mask what you were saying because of the backticks? Is the input line you describe supposed to have backticks? (Btw, Happy St. Patrick's Day -- almost one year late)

Comment: @snapfractalpop: you are right, the text was mangled.  The original texts were: **If you can have <backslash> in your input, do not forget to use the -r argument to read** *and* **yes, you need to use -r, because if you have an input line like `box1 foo<backslash>nbar` without -r you will loose the <backslash>** with backticks around <backslash> and -r for the formatting of the comments.

The general rule here is that if you use `read`, you probably need `-r`.  With and without `-r`, the following will give different results: `echo "box1 foo<backslash>nbar" | { read -r txt; echo "$txt"; }`.

Comment: `read` with two variables isn't working for me. At least not with `IFS=$'\n'`

Answer (score 2):

To store the variables into the current shell:

```bash
~$ {
read -r a
read -r b
read -r c
} < <(printf '%s\n' one two three)
$ echo "a=$a b=$b c=$c"
a=one b=two c=three
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree" | {
read -r a; 
read -r b; 
read -r c;
echo "output of ($a, $b, $c)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, to avoid `read` from going into subshell, so that variables remain in scope:

```bash
fn() { echo "1 2 3"; }

IFS=' ' read -r A B C <<< "$(fn)"

echo "A=$A B=$B C=$C"
# => A=1 B=2 C=3
```