# How to use multiple variable in for loop in sh?

Tags: bash, sh

I want to use multiple variable in for loop at once in sh.

I have a query like this:

```
top -n 1 -b -c| awk -vOFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$9}'
```

I know i use for loop in bash like this:

```
for i in {2..10}
do
    echo "output: $i"
done
```

what i want to try is:

```
for x y z in $(top -n 1 -b -c| awk -vOFS="\t" {print $1,$2,$9}')
do
    echo "output: $x $y $z"
done
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pipe a file line by line into multiple read variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442220/how-do-i-pipe-a-file-line-by-line-into-multiple-read-variables)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906232/how-to-read-variables-from-file-with-multiple-variables-per-line

Comment: `top -n 1 -b -c | while read -r x y _ _ _ _ _ _ z _; do echo "output: $x $y $z"; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe to a `while read` loop:

```
top -n 1 -b -c| awk -vOFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$9}' | while IFS=$'\t' read -r x y z
do
    echo "output: $x $y $z"
done
```